# Creating C++ stl forward iterator given numpy array using Boost::Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, boost-python

I'm having trouble creating a boost python forward iterator to get a numpy array as input of a C++ function that takes an stl begin and end iterator as a template and modifies it, here's the code for the C++ function:

```
template<typename _InputIt>
void vec_fill_increasing(_InputIt begin, _InputIt end, typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIt>::value_type start, typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIt>::value_type increment)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIt>::value_type _Type;
    if (std::is_floating_point<_Type>::value)
    {
        std::size_t count = 0;
        while (begin != end)
        {
        *begin = start + ((_Type)count*increment);
        ++begin;
        ++count;
        }
    }
    else {

        while (begin != end)
        {
            *begin = start;
            start += increment;
            ++begin;
        }
}
```

There is already an implementation of an stl input iterator in Boost Python (i.e. **stl_iterator.hpp**) but it's not mutable, so that won't help me here, so I tried to create my own stl_forward_iterator based on the input iterator.

```
namespace boost {
    namespace python
    {
        // An STL forward iterator over a python sequence
        template<typename ValueT>
        struct stl_forward_iterator
        : boost::iterator_facade<
            stl_forward_iterator<ValueT>
            , ValueT
            , std::forward_iterator_tag
        >
        {
            stl_forward_iterator()
            : impl_()
            {
            }

            // ob is the python sequence
            stl_forward_iterator(boost::python::object const &ob)
            : impl_(ob)
            {
            }

        private:
            friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

            void increment()
            {
                this->impl_.increment();
            }

            ValueT& dereference() const
            {
                return extract<ValueT&>(this->impl_.current().get())();
            }

            bool equal(stl_forward_iterator<ValueT> const &that) const
            {
                return this->impl_.equal(that.impl_);
            }

            objects::stl_input_iterator_impl impl_;
        };
    }
}
```

The only change I really made was changing the return of the deference function to a reference instead of just a value.

And I use this in my main application as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void wrap_fill_increasing(boost::python::numeric::array& array, T start, T increment) {
   boost::python::stl_forward_iterator<T> begin(array);
   boost::python::stl_forward_iterator<T> end;
   vec_fill_increasing(begin, end, start, increment);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    import_array();
    p::numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");
    p::def("fill_increasing", &wrap_fill_increasing<int>);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("example", &PyInit_example);
    
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString(
    "import example\n"
    "import numpy\n"
    "z3 = numpy.zeros((1024,), dtype=numpy.int)\n"
    "example.fill_increasing(z3, 0, 1)\n"
    "print(z3)\n"
    );

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

But I get the error:

> **TypeError: No registered converter was able to extract a C++ reference to type int from this Python object of type numpy.int32**

And it occurs on the dereference function in my stl_forward_iterator and I don't know how to resolve this.

If something that can help in this scenario doesn't exist, I really think there should be one as a suggestion, unless there is a different solution.